# How can i remove udefind while im uisng forloop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

while im binding values im getting values as undefinedAnil Singh1,Sunil Singh2,Sushil3,Aradhya4,Reena5,Here how can i remove undefind

```
$scope.GetData = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i <$scope.employee.length; i++) {
            var abc = $scope.employee[i];
            angular.forEach(abc, function (value, key) {               
                if (key == "name") 
                    {
                        if ($scope.emailNames != "undefined") {

                     $scope.emailNames = $scope.emailNames + value + ",";
                            console.log($scope.emailNames);
                        }
                    }
            })
```

Comment: why minus is their any thing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're looking for string comparison, but *undefined* in Javascript is not a string.

That means your check:

```
if ($scope.emailNames != "undefined")
```

Passes, then you concatenate *$scope.emailNames* with a new string, and that converts the *undefined* value to hist string version: *"undefined"* that you find in your console output.

To demostrate that try this code:

```
var x;
var y = x + "some new string";
console.log(y);
```

You got:

> undefinedsome new string

To solve the issue you need to fix the *if* statement:

```
if ($scope.emailNames !== undefined)
```

Please notice I used *!==* that check if *$scope.emailNames* are the same type too.

This means that if you have a null it will fail again, and you'll find *nullsome new string* in your log.

In such a case just use the *!=* with only 1 equal, that consider *null* values just like as *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check for undefined and not "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Use .substring() methode like below

```
 $scope.GetData = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i <$scope.employee.length; i++) {
            var abc = $scope.employee[i];
            angular.forEach(abc, function (value, key) {               
                if (key == "name") 
                    {
                        if ($scope.emailNames != "undefined") {
                            $scope.emailNames = $scope.emailNames + value + ",";
                            var res = $scope.emailNames.substring(9);
                            console.log(res);
                        }


  }
        })
```